# Django Rest Framework - JSON Post Request ManyTomany field issue

Tags: python, json, django, post, django-rest-framework

TLDR; using Django Rest Framework, how can I make a POST (application/json content) to an API Resource that has a Many to Many Relation Field using only the ID/PK for said M2M field?

I'm currently modeling an application for a college project that used Django Rest Framework. The following model represents a Volunteer on the application (I've hidden some minor details to avoid polluting the code)

```
class Volunteer(models.Model):

first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=13) 
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(max_length=500)  
photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
interest_areas = models.ManyToManyField(VolunteeringArea, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Volunteers"
    ordering = ("first_name", "last_name")

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('volunteers:volunteer-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

And the respective serializer looks like this:

```
class VolunteerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    interest_areas = VolunteeringAreaSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Volunteer
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'email', 'state', 'gender', 'interest_areas', 'city', 'description', 'photo')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', )


    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(VolunteerSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['interest_areas'] = VolunteeringAreaSerializer(instance.interest_areas.all(), many=True).data
        return representation
```

As you may notice, each Volunteer may have many Interested areas attributed to it (Many to Many Field). The following model represents it:

```
class VolunteeringArea(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "VolunteeringAreas"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title

)
```

And the respective serializer is:

```
class VolunteeringAreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = VolunteeringArea
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'is_active')
```

My problem is that, when trying to create a new Volunteer through POST (application/json) providing the ID of the interested_area, I get a response saying that I should have provided a dict, but the application received an int instead. I realize that the application was expecting a complete dict with all of the fields from the interested_area, but I wanted to provide the ID/PK only and it would create the object.

I've been looking for hours on the internet and it seems like I should first create the object without the interest_areas, and then add them to the object. I've tried to define a create method on the views.py of the module (same as the original create method defined by the framework), but it seems to get stuck at serializer.is_valid(), most likely indicating that the values provided at the interested_area field are not valid.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    return self.create(request)


def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

What is my error, and how can I make this work?

For the sake of information, this is the body content of the request, using Postman:

```
{
    "interest_areas": [0,1],
    "first_name":"NameOfThePerson",
    "last_name":"LastNameOfThePerson",
    "phone":"RandomCellphoneNumber",
    "email":"randomemail@randomemail.com",
    "gender":"Gender",
    "state":"State",
    "city":"City",
    "description":"randomDescription"
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi, I use your code, it works with ""interest_areas": [1]," , but failed if I pass two value`"interest_areas": [0,1],`, it says `1062, \"Duplicate entry '315' for key 'XXXX_code'\"`, do you know the reason why I can't pass more than two value in that list?

Comment: Please ignore my question, it's the table's problem, it's solved now its working perfectly ☕️ Thanks so much for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you have included the `VolunteeringAreaSerializer` as a NestedSerialiser. To use only the IDs for your VolunteeringArea, use PrimaryKeyRelatedField and bulk_create like this.

```
class VolunteerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    interest_areas = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, 
                     queryset=models.VolunteeringArea.objects.all())


    class Meta:
        model = Volunteer
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'email', 'state', 
              'gender', 'interest_areas', 'city', 'description', 'photo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        areas = validated_data.pop('interest_areas', [])
        # create your volunteer here..
        #......
        ThroughModel = Volunteer.interest_areas.through
        # bulk-create through model instance fields
        ThroughModel.objects.bulk_create([
                ThroughModel(volunteer_id=<freshly_created_volunteer_id>, 
                         interest_area_id=area_id)
                        for area_id in areas
                      ])

        return volunteer
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the PrimarykeyRelatedField was the "key" to solving the issue and now its working perfectly :)